# I can´t add multiple .bib files

Tags: bibliographies

I´m Trying to put the references at the last of every chapter, like one more section of the chapter.

I have two problems doing that:
1) The new section "Bibliography" that appear in the first chapter, has the same sectioning number that the last section in the chapter.

2) In the chapters 2, 3, 4, etc appear the same bibliography of the chapter 1, even when I add the others `.bib` files.

Im using

```
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
```

in the main file `Thesis.tex`

`bib1.bib`:

```
@book{1book:684949,
   title =     {Optics},
   author =    {Eugene Hecht},
   publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
   isbn =      {0321188780,9780321188786},
   year =      {2002},
   series =    {},
   edition =   {},
   volume =    {}
   }

@Book{1ewart,
  Title                    = {Atomic Physics},
  Author                   = {Paul Ewart},
  Publisher                = {Oxford University Press, USA},
  Year                     = {2008}
 }
```

`bib2.bib`:

```
@article{2Zeeman,
    author    = "C. Cohen-Tannoudji; J. Dupont-Roc",
    title     = "Experimental Study of Zeeman Light Shifts in Weak Magnetic           Fields",
    journal   = "Physical Review A",
    volume   = "5",
    number   = "2",
    year      = "1972",
   %month    = "",
   %note     = "",
}

@article{2nonlinear,
    author    = "D. Budker; W. Gawlik; D. Kimball; S. Rochester; V. Yashchuk;        A. Weis",
    title     = "Resonant nonlinear magneto-optical effects in atoms",
    journal   = "Reviews of Modern Physics",
    volume   = "74",
    number   = "4",
    %pages    = "",
    year      = "2002",
   %month    = "",
   %note     = "",
 }
```

In chapter 1:

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib1}
```

In chapter 2:

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib2}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You might consider using `biblatex` and its `refsection` environment, which is done for that (§ 3.6.5 of the documentation).

Comment: There are [several ways](https://www.ctan.org/topic/bibtex-multi) to solve this problem. If you aren't tied to BibTeX by a publisher, however, consider using `biblatex`.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Are you `\include{}`ing each chapter? If not you need to use the `{cbunit}` or `\cbinput` stuff to allow multiple bibliographies without `\include{}`.

Comment: Excellent, @cfr .It works!

Answer (score 3):

[chapterbib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chapterbib) requires one of the following two conditions be satisfied.

1. Each chapter is written in a separate file and is incorporated into the main document using `\include{}`. In this case, a separate bibliography may be created for each chapter, using the relevant commands in each chapter's own `.tex` file.
2. If the chapters are not in separate files or `\include{}` is not used then the environment `{cbunit}` or macro `\cbinput` may be used to divide the document into parts with separate bibliographies. In this case, the relevant commands for each bibliography must be within the scope of the appropriate environment or macro.

An altogether easier alternative is provided by [Biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) although that option does, admittedly, introduce its own complexities as a function of the additional flexibility and power it provides.